# OpenGL object loader

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

I'm following a tutorial on Youtube for OpenGL with LWJGL 3 game development by ThinMatrix. Got to loading custom .obj files. I can only run the provided stall and dragon object. Cannot run my own models created with Blender 2.78. Getting this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at tk.kerdo.gfx.OBJLoader.processVertex(OBJLoader.java:97)
```

My .obj loader: https://pastebin.com/zSVDtsRr
My .obj file: https://pastebin.com/k5LZFsRN

How can I change my .obj loader engine to work with my current and new models?

Thanks,

Kerdo K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your obj file doesn't have UV coordinates. Make sure you unwrap your object before you export it ([Here's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh) how you do it in blender)

Comment: Thank you! Got it working after trying that!
Now just have to tinker around with the settings and I'll be done!

Comment: You also have to triangulate your 3d model before exporting to the game engine, since yourobj loader doesn't support anything else

Comment: (modern) Opengl doesn't support anything else. Also I would pick a different format than obj. It's horrible as a asset format.